# Not able to open pre-installed database using Sqlite AssetHelper library

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on pre-installed database and using [SqliteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) library for that.

This is my db code

```
public class DBController extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "user.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private final String TABLE_NAME = "User";

    public DBController(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public ArrayList<UserData> getAllUserData() {

        ArrayList<UserData> data_list = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            // open database to query
            SQLiteDatabase mySqliteDb = getWritableDatabase();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("exception", "" + e);
        }

        close();
        return data_list;
    }
}
```

**Error:  Missing databases/user.db file (or .zip, .gz archive) in assets, or target folder not writable**

and when I change my code to  `SQLiteDatabase mySqliteDb = getReadableDatabase();` I am getting **android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database** error.

I search for the problem and mostly everyon saying check your db present inside databases folder or not.

[image]

I tried using zip also still no luck. I guess I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `assets/` directory belongs inside `main/`, not inside `app/`.